# How to disable error messages in editr.js

Tags: editor, ace-editor

I'm using the editr.js editor on my documentation site to load and display gists, which works great. Is there a way to disable the error messages in *.js and *.css files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update editr.css file

```
.editr__editor--invalid:before {
    display: none;
}
```